# Save sheet as values in external file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 6 sheets.
I want to save the **values** (not formulas) of the sheets 1 and 2 in 2 external files.

Tried this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:="D:\sheet1.xls", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False
End With

Worksheets("Sheet2").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:="D:\sheet2.xls", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False
End With
```

It Works. But:

1. It's saving the formulas, not its values.
2. If file exists, prompt a message asking if want to override

Comment: Thats because you didn't tell excel to save it as values. You just specified the .xls fileformat as per https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm

Comment: I'm trying to tell excel to save it as values, but can't found the way. Microsoft is not explaining it its documentation of workbook.saveas https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to convert the formulas into values on your own. Do something like the following:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy 'create a copy in a new workbook

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'get the new workbook

'change formulas into values
wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value

'save
wb.SaveAs Filename:="D:\sheet1.xls", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False

'close it
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

If you want to get rid of the overwriting question, check if the file `D:\sheet1.xls` alrady exists and kill it before you save it. I don't explain that in detail because there are already one million tutorials for that.

---

**Improvement**

Use a procedure to re-use your code:

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheet(ByVal SheetName As String, ByVal ExportToFile As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Copy 

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value

    If Dir(ExportToFile) <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportToFile
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=ExportToFile, FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Sub TestIt()
    ExportWorksheet SheetName:="Sheet1" ExportToFile:="D:\sheet1.xls"
    ExportWorksheet SheetName:="Sheet2" ExportToFile:="D:\sheet2.xls"
End Sub
```

Note whenever you feel you would have to copy a code, split it apart into a seperate procedure to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Thank you, it works very well.
I killed using: 
If Dir("D:\sheet1.xls") <> "" Then
    Kill "D:\sheet1.xls"
End If

Comment: What do you mean by code is too long? Write a export procedure that you can call then: `Public Sub ExportWorksheet(SheetName As String, ExportToFile As String)` and call it like `ExportWorksheet SheetName:="Sheet1", ExportToFile:="D:\sheet1.xls"` so you can re-use it for any sheet and export path.

Comment: @PEH, thank you very much. It solves all my questions!

Comment: @PEH, "If Dir(ExportToFile) <> vbNullString Then Kill ExportToFile", must before the saving (by just in case you want to fix your answer)

Comment: @Josías copy/paste fail :) Fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @PEH I just noticed a new "problem": your code copies also the powequery connections of the original workbook. I could remove it after, but much better if the code don't copy the connections, and only values. is there a  way to copy just the cell values without the related connections?

Comment: @Josías easiest way would be to kick them off after. Alternatively, instead of copying the whole sheet you can create an empty sheet and copy paste the values and formatting of the desired range only. But then you will lose things like column width and row heights etc.

Answer (score 1):

A small example which may help:    Option Explicit

```
Sub test()

    Dim wsSou As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook

        Set wsSou = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDes = .Worksheets("Sheet2")

        'Copy Paste - ONLY Values
        wsSou.UsedRange.Copy
        wsDes.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Copy Paste - Values and Formattings
        wsSou.UsedRange.Copy wsDes.Range("A1")

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Careful: This will not take any formattings, numberformattings, column widths, etc. into account. For example a date `2019-06-25` will turn ito its bare number `43641`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you are right. the OP ask  for the values that why i use the `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
`

Comment: Yes, the question was actually not really clear about if he wants to keep formattings or not.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have change the answer to cover both aspects. Any feedback?

Comment: Actually `wsSou.UsedRange.Copy wsDes.Range("A1")` would copy the formulas (not the values). Things like *column widths* are also only copied if you copy full columns or the whole sheet.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. i will remove my answer

Comment: Actually the `wsDes.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` was not wrong. It just depends what the OP wants. He wasn't clear about that. Just because I wrote a note doen't mean you have to change it. I suggest to just remove `wsSou.UsedRange.Copy wsDes.Range("A1")` which is the opposite of what the OP wanted and keep the answer.